# Difference between adding a Reference and adding a Nuget package to a project in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, external

I have a VS (2015) project. I see there's a "References" section in the Solution Explorer view of my project that includes things like System.Core. I'm assuming these are .dlls that have been added to the project?

I can also right-click on the project file (again in the Solution Explorer) and select the option to "Manage NuGet Packages". I know the NuGet allows me to add external code to my project (e.g. external .dlls and associated files).

What's the difference between adding a reference to my project and adding a .nupkg to my project? Is it just that .nupkg can contain a whole bunch of other things aside from a .dll (e.g. documentation)? Why would I use one or the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What's the difference between adding a reference to my project and
> adding a .nupkg to my project?

NuGet essentially does not differ from manually adding references, and ultimately adds references to the project. It is a tool that automatically adds assemblies to us and manages them, effectively improving the efficiency of our development projects.

For more details, you can check [the document about nuget](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/what-is-nuget):

> Put simply, a NuGet package is a single ZIP file with the .nupkg extension that contains compiled code (DLLs), other files related to that code, and a descriptive manifest that includes information like the package's version number. Developers with code to share create packages and publish them to a public or private host. **Package consumers obtain those packages from suitable hosts, add them to their projects, and then call a package's functionality in their project code. NuGet itself then handles all of the intermediate details.**
>
> Because NuGet supports private hosts alongside the public nuget.org host, you can use NuGet packages to share code that's exclusive to an organization or a work group. You can also use NuGet packages as a convenient way to factor your own code for use in nothing but your own projects. In short, a NuGet package is a shareable unit of code, but does not require nor imply any particular means of sharing.

.

> Is it just that .nupkg can contain a whole bunch of other things aside
> from a .dll (e.g. documentation)?

Yes, NuGet package could include specify files in the package.

> Why would I use one or the other?

Nuget provides several additional benefits:

- it automatically configures your projects by adding references to the
  necessary assemblies, creating and adding project files (e.g.
  configuration), etc.
- it provides package updates
- it does all of this very conveniently

I'm sure that once you use it, you'll realize that it has many benefits.

Check [Why use NuGet](https://www.daniellittle.xyz/why-use-nuget/) for more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice answer, thanks. The link Why use Nuget link was also very helpful.